# How to print Object in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx

i am trying to print object values in JSX, when i use map, error shows `TypeError: users.items.map is not a function`

here is my object shows redux logger

```
Action 
type: "USERS_GETALL_SUCCESS"
users: Object { _id: "5c049e1b96848f0b9a6f9032", email: "mail@mail.com"}
```

when i console user in JSX

```
items: Object { _id: "5c049e1b96848f0b9a6f9032", email: "mail@mail.com"}
```

Comment: You can get the keys with Object.keys and map over them.

Answer (score 0):

items is not array 
it's object . So object has not map method

try log items.email

you have object structure like this

```
users {
   items: {
      id: 1,
      email: '@'
   }
}
```

Comment: how to convert it